# Excel VBA error 1004 when using range

Tags: vba, excel, range, runtime-error

I have a work in VBA where I need to make a square size of 512X512 (cellsXcells).
The square suppose to be with the borders of the cells.
I made the size of the square dynamic so user can insert the size he wants (max is 512).

Now I tried with few techniques to do the above but always I fail because of error 1004 run time.

```
Sub printGrid(gridSize)

Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(gridSize, gridSize)).Select
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThick
End With

With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThick
End With



With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThick
End With

With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThick
End With

With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThick
End With

End With

End Sub
```

My second attempt was to do it cell by cell...

```
Sub printBorders(gridSize)
For i = 1 To gridSize ' right side
    Cells(i, 1).Select
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThick
    End With
Next i


For i = 1 To gridSize ' bottom
    Cells(gridSize, i).Select
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThick
    End With
Next i

For i = gridSize To 1 Step -1 ' top
    Cells(1, i).Select
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThick
    End With
Next i

For i = 1 To gridSize ' center
    Cells(i, 64).Select
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThick
    End With
Next i



For i = 1 To gridSize ' left
    Cells(i, gridSize).Select
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThick
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

At printBorders I fail when I try to make the left grid. (Cells(i, gridSize).Select).

I am starting to think that this is sort kind of a limit in excel.
Thanks for the help!

EDIT:

When I mean dynamic:
Please trying running it with inputs like 64 or 512.

```
Sub main()
Dim gridSize As Integer, numOfDots As Integer
Call setGrid
End Sub

Sub setGrid()
Dim size As Integer
Cells.Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

gridSize = setGridSize()

Call printGrid2(1, 1, gridSize, gridSize)
'Call printGrid2(1, 1, gridSize, gridSize / 2)

End Sub

Function setGridSize()
Do While True
    gridSize = InputBox("Enter grid size:")
    If (IsNumeric(gridSize)) And (gridSize Mod 2 = 0) Then
        setGridSize = gridSize
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
End Function

Sub printGrid2(x, y, rowSize, colSize)
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range(Cells(x, y), Cells(rowSize, colSize))


With rng.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThick
End With

With rng.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThick
End With

With rng.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThick
End With

With rng.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThick
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the worksheet, or any part of it *Protected*? If so, you may not be able to select or perform certain actions. Also, [it's generally advisable to avoid relying on `Select` or `Activate`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251).

Comment: So instead of `Cells(i, 1).Select` and `With Selection...` just do `With Cells(i, 1).Borders(xlEdgeLeft)`. But if the sheet is protected, you still may not be able to do that.

Comment: What is the idea of this `Cells(i, 64).Select` ? It goes to Column `BL`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with protection. Even if i put a small input like 64, when it reaches line Cells(i, gridSize).Select when it is trying to do the left side, it crash with runtime error
@DavidZemens I will try using Dim rng as Range and update.

Comment: @user3449011 - well, bot codes "work" for me. Try openning an empty Excel file and run them there.

Comment: @Vityata try running it dynamic. Create a msgbox and enter value like 64. Then run it. When I don't do it dynamic it works. Any suggestions?

Comment: While it's a good idea to use properly assigned range variables, that doesn't seem likely to solve the problem in this case. 1004 usually indicates a Protection issue, or that you've defined an inaccessible object (e.g., `Cells(0, 2)` will fail because it doesn't/can't exist.

Comment: @user3449011 - I run it dynamically. It works.

Comment: Worth noting that YOUR code does not raise any error (apart from the compile error, which can be resolved by declaring your variables properly) when I run it in a blank workbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I run the code, "dynamically". After removing `Option Explicit`, on a new Excel and trying not to look at the selections, it works:

```
Sub DynamicTest()

    printBorders (10)
    printBorders (20)
    printBorders (30)
    printBorders (InputBox("Dynamically"))

End Sub

Sub printBorders(gridSize As Long)
    For i = 1 To gridSize    ' right side
        Cells(i, 1).Select
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThick
        End With
    Next i


    For i = 1 To gridSize    ' bottom
        Cells(gridSize, i).Select
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThick
        End With
    Next i

    For i = gridSize To 1 Step -1    ' top
        Cells(1, i).Select
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThick
        End With
    Next i

    For i = 1 To gridSize    ' center
        Cells(i, 64).Select
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThick
        End With
    Next i



    For i = 1 To gridSize    ' left
        Cells(i, gridSize).Select
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThick
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

This is what I have changed:

From:
`Sub printBorders(gridSize)`

To:
`Sub printBorders(gridSize As Long)`

Or you may ask for a numeric input in the InputBox like this:
`InputBox("Dynamically", Type:=1)`. (Credit to *David Zemens*)

**In general, this is why the error appears:**

The `Cells` takes [parameter overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) in VBA. This means, that you can refer to Cells with any of these two:

`Cells(Long, Long)`     -> `Cells(1,1)`

`Cells(Long, String)`  -> `Cells(1,"A")`

`gridSize` is a `String`, but it is no problem to be used in a `for-loop` as such, because it is internally casted to a Numeric value.

However, when you try to select `Cells(i, gridSize)`, VBA looks for the function `Cells(Long, String)` first. It expects that the `String` is a column name. However, you do not have a column named `111`, thus it throws an error.
[image]

Comment: Why did you remove `Option Explicit`? Seems better to just declare the variable `i` :)

Comment: @DavidZemens - but you are not using it `Dynamically`, passing a `String` value from the `InputBox` as a parameter :) Then, indeed, you get a `1004` error somewhere on the last `for-loop`.

Comment: @Vityata this is not dynamic. Please see the post.

Comment: No, I'm not, but that can be handled by simply type-casting the return from InputBox, or requiring the InputBox to return numeric values :)

Comment: @user3449011 - see the edit, now it is dynamic. Plus, the 4. time I am calling from an InputBox.

Comment: `InputBox("Dynamically", Type:=1)` will *require* a numeric input

Comment: @DavidZemens - true, let it be so, I edited the post.

Comment: @Vityata The problem was that i used Integer instead of Long (not sure why.). Thanks for help everyone.

Comment: In your original code change only to this -> `gridSize = InputBox("Enter grid size:",type:=1)`. Then it should actually work as well. @user3449011

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading this correctly, all you want to do is draw a square grid with surrounding borders. You do not have to perform the individual operations.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    printGrid 6
End Sub

Sub printGrid(gridSize)
    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        With .Cells(1, 1).Resize(gridSize, gridSize)
            .BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThick
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Recorded code often performs much more than is necessary. It is best to chop it down to what is actually needed.

[image]

Comment: Just the borders, without borders for the internal cells.

Comment: OK, adjusted per your requirements above.

Comment: but you do not have the **animation** effect from the selection of the cells :)

Comment: Well, maybe I could import some kernel functions and make the cursor dance a bit. :D